# Masking fails when due to 'assertion failed' ... sameSize

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to create an image that is only the top white polygon filled with the e.g. beige coloured image, so that when I run minMaxLoc I won't get the masked off area in the result. My mask and region of interest are the same size, `100 x 100` artificially so, to debug this. The error appears to be that they are not the same size.

```
#the mask
mask = np.zeros((100, 100))
cv2.fillPoly(mask,[pts],True,255)
mask = mask[0:100, 0:100]

#the region
roi = image[0:100, 0:100]
cv2.bitwise_and(roi, roi, mask = mask)

cv2.imshow('image',roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

`error: (-215:Assertion failed) (mtype == CV_8U || mtype == CV_8S) && _mask.sameSize(*psrc1) in function 'binary_op'`

Images showing
[mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YcBd.png),
[region](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S2KxZ.png)

Edit

If this approach is bound to fail then I have tried skipping creating a mask from which to sample and sampling directly using the mask parameters in the sampling function:

`(minVal, maxVal, minLoc, maxLoc) = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray, mask)`

that produces empty mask error:

`error: (-215:Assertion failed) (cn == 1 && (_mask.empty() || _mask.type() == CV_8U)) 
|| (cn > 1 && _mask.empty() && !minIdx && !maxIdx) in function 'minMaxIdx'`

Comment: this may be due to mask type which mine has none

Comment: Be careful of the `dtype` with Python, try `mask = np.zeros((100, 100), dtype=np.uint8)` And check with `print(mask.dtype)`

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by changing the problem slightly.
Make sure to convert the mask to the correct type and then call = minMax with the mask parameter directly

```
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(orig, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    minMaxLoc = cv2.minMaxLoc(gray, mask = mask)
```